# VB.Net Runtime BackgroundWorkers to retrieve data

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

After reading many articles on SO regarding background workers and multi-threading, I have working code that I would like to ask your opinion on.  The challenge is to retrieve data on a separate thread and update the UI with the contents.  I went with runtime BGW's because of trouble I was having with Invoke; as well as the convenience of RunWorkerCompleted.

Could you look at the code and see if it is reasonable and sound in its approach?  (I haven't added Progress Updates etc.)

```
Public Class BgwArgs                'args object to pass to BGW
    Public sSql As String           'query to be run by DoWork
    Public dbTable As DataTable     'return data to this table
    Public lst As ListBox           'populate this control with returned data
End Class

Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    'get new BGW, may be multiple BGW's running at a time
    Dim myBgw As BackgroundWorker = fGetBgw()
    Dim sArgs As New BgwArgs   'set Args
    sArgs.sSql = "BHRow"       'just a test string, would really be a query
    sArgs.lst = lstBH          'control to populate
    myBgw.RunWorkerAsync(sArgs)
End Sub

Private Function fGetBgw() As BackgroundWorker
   'create New backgroundworker and addhandlers
    Dim newBgw As New BackgroundWorker
    myBgw.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    myBgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    AddHandler myBgw.DoWork, AddressOf WorkerDoWork
    AddHandler myBgw.ProgressChanged, AddressOf WorkerProgressChanged
    AddHandler myBgw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf WorkerCompleted
    Return newBgw
End Function

Private Sub WorkerDoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)
    Thread.Sleep(3000)  'kill time as a test
    Dim sArgs As BgwArgs = e.Argument
    pGetDbTable(sArgs)    'pass in Args to DataQuery
    e.Result = sArgs      'set result for use in Completed event
End Sub

Private Sub WorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    Dim sArgs As BgwArgs = e.Result
    Dim tbl As DataTable = sArgs.dbTable
    Dim lb As ListBox = sArgs.lst
    Dim thisBgw As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)

    If e.Cancelled = True Then

    ElseIf e.Error IsNot Nothing Then
        MsgBox(e.Error.Message)

    Else

        For Each row As DataRow In tbl.Rows
            'update UI, bind data here, etc.
            lb.Items.Add(row("col1").ToString)
        Next
        RemoveHandler thisBgw.DoWork, AddressOf WorkerDoWork
        RemoveHandler thisBgw.ProgressChanged, AddressOf WorkerProgressChanged
        RemoveHandler thisBgw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf WorkerCompleted
     Endif

End Sub

Private Sub pGetDbTable(sArgs As BgwArgs)
    Dim tbl As New DataTable
    'would really run a SQL query here... and return the Datatable
    With tbl
        .Columns.Add("col1")
        Dim i As Integer
        For i = 0 To 200
            .Rows.Add(sArgs.sSql & i)
        Next
        sArgs.dbTable = tbl
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Is there anything about it that isn't working or doesn't seem like it may be quite right to you?

Comment: I think you nailed it.  Just make sure to utilize any UI methods that allow you to update the control without continually refreshing.  With the ListBox, for instance, you'd use `lb.BeginUpdate()` before the For loop, and `lb.EndUpdate()` afterwards.
`

Comment: Thanks Steven, this does work and Idle_Mind, I do set the begin/end_updates :-).  I was wondering if I was missing anything like do I need to remove the handlers?  I could do this in the RunWorkerCompleted - please see the modified code.  Also do you think I need to dispose of each Backgroundworker?

Comment: In terms of disposing with backgroundworkers, this code will be run off a timer, thereby refreshing a grid on a set interval - possibly hundreds of times per day.  Do I need to be concerned that the workers created (in StartClick in this example) will cause memory issues etc. or will they be disposed of when they go out of scope?
If a background process is running and the user closes the form that the bgw was created in, does that cause a problem, or is the bgw disposed and GC'd along with the form?

Comment: If the runs don't overlap each other then I would create just one BackgroundWorker and keep it at Form level.  A BackgroundWorker thread has IsBackground() set to True which allows it to be cancelled automatically when the form closes.